# trying to format x and y coordinates using .format() function

Tags: python

So I have an assignment where I have the user input a few numbers and it draws a shape based on the number and length input.  As the turtle draws the picture it is supposed to report the X and Y coordinates and heading after each turn; however the X and Y coordinates need to be formatted as integers so that they display a whole number instead of a decimal.  I'm supposed to use the .format() function to do so but I have no idea where and how to use it.

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle
lawrence = tur  tle.Turtle()
lawrence.goto(-150,0)
lawrence.pencolor('white')
lawrence.speed(2)

#setup of window that final image will be displayed on
window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(1000,1000)
window.title("Homework 3")
window.bgcolor('black')


user_shape = int(input('What do you want me to draw? (1 = square, 2 = triangle): '))
if user_shape == 1:
print('I will draw a square')
else:
print('I will draw an equilateral triangle')

user_length = int(input('How long do you want the sides of your square to be? Please enter the number of pixels (e.g. 100): '))

for num in range(user_shape):
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 1st corner is at: ',lawrence.xcor().format(),',',lawrence.ycor(), 'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 2nd corner is at: ',lawrence.xcor(),',',lawrence.ycor(), 'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 3rd corner is at: ',lawrence.xcor(),',',lawrence.ycor(), 'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 4th corner is at: ',lawrence.xcor(),',',lawrence.ycor(), 'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())

window.exitonclick()
```

I'm only in a basic python programming class and just need to know how to use the .format() function and where so any help would be great

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------
that first part of my code works great but I have another problem now.. I have to ask the user for a second input on a second shape ( so after the first shape is drawn and recorded the prompt asks for a second shape to draw and record)

```
import turtle
lawrence = turtle.Turtle()
lawrence.goto(-150,0)
lawrence.pencolor('white')
lawrence.speed(2)

#setup of window that final image will be displayed on
window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(1000,1000)
window.title("Homework 3")
window.bgcolor('black')


user_shape = int(input('What do you want me to draw? (1 = square, 2 = triangle): '))
if user_shape == 1:
    print('I will draw a square')
    user_length = int(input('How long do you want the sides of your square to be? Please enter the number of pixels (e.g. 100): '))
    for num in range(user_shape):
        lawrence.forward(user_length)
        lawrence.left(90)
        print('My 1st corner is at: ','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor()),',','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.ycor()),'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 2nd corner is at: ','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor()),',','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.ycor()),'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 3rd corner is at: ','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor()),',','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.ycor()),'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
    lawrence.forward(user_length)
    lawrence.left(90)
    print('My 4th corner is at: ','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor()),',','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.ycor()),'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
if user_shape == 2:
    print('I will draw an equilateral triangle')
    user_length = int(input('How long do you want the sides of your triangle to be? Please enter the number of pixels (e.g. 100): '))
    for num in range(user_shape):
        lawrence.forward(user_length)
        lawrence.left(135)
        print('My 1st corner is at: ','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor()),',','{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.ycor()),'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())

window.exitonclick()
```

so the issue that i'm having is that the program reports 2 coordinates even with only one output and I've discovered that when you press 2 to indicate you want a triangle to be drawn and then indicate the length of the sides the program is taking the '2' input from the user and multiplying it by the number of coordinates it needs to report.  so instead of drawing out a line and reporting x,y coordinates and heading it reports x,y coordinated and heading and then a second set of x,y coordinates and heading even though only one line of outputs is coded. 
so ya need help there too

Comment: Time to learn searching the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to convert your coordinates to integer numbers then correct formatting would be (I am showing only the first `print` statement):

```
print('My 1st corner is at: {:d},{:d} and my heading is {}'.format(int(lawrence.xcor()), int(lawrence.ycor()), lawrence.heading())
```

or if you need to *round* floating point numbers, replace `int(lawrence.xcor())` with `int(round(lawrence.xcor()))`.

If you are not allowed to convert coordinates to integers, then use the following formatting:

```
print('My 1st corner is at: {:.0f},{:.0f} and my heading is {}'.format(lawrence.xcor(), lawrence.ycor(), lawrence.heading())
```

Comment: Using `int()` on a float will truncate instead of rounding.

Comment: @Blurp True, but it is not clear from OP what is preferred or if it matters. The question was chiefly about formatting. _"...coordinates need to be formatted as integers so that they display a whole number instead of a decimal."_ - this does not tell which way to convert floats to ints.

Comment: My upvote is for your second option. I think it's the best answer.

Comment: the number displays as a float like 150.00000000000003 and I need it to display as an integer like 150. the response below by Blurp worked best for me

Comment: @LawrenceMaizon The issue is: if the number displays as a float like 150.800000000003 - do you want it to be displayed as 150 or as 151?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `lawrence.xcor().format()` with `'{0:.0f}'.format(lawrence.xcor())`.

Comment: Thank you. that worked perfectly! My professor never openly taught us how to use the .format() function so thank you

Answer (score 0):

String format is a very powerful tool to output text in various forms. If you are aiming to write simple and readable code I recommend reading through this chapter (I always go back to it myself): https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Now to your question: if you are going to use the same pattern repeatedly you can first define the string (outside the loop), e.g.:

```
p_string = 'My {} corner is at: {:.0f},{:.0f} and my heading is {}'
```

You simply put the unkown `{}` where you want to insert a string. Now you can go ahead and print:

```
print(p_string.format("1st",*lawrence.pos(), lawrence.heading()))
```

...

```
print(p_string.format("2nd",*lawrence.pos(), lawrence.heading()))
```

The `*` before `lawrence.pos()`unpacks the tuple/list (meaning it is equivalent to: `lawrence.xcor(), lawrence.ycor()`)

Answer (score -1):

from

```
print('My 1st corner is at: ',lawrence.xcor().format(),',',lawrence.ycor(), 'and my heading is',lawrence.heading())
```

to

```
print_str = 'My 1st corner is at: ({}, {}), and my heading is {}'.format(lawrence.xcor(), lawrence.ycor(), lawrence.heading())
print(print_str)
```